# Snakemake report - Code not displayed in the report

Tags: snakemake

I am using Snakemake version 5.1 ' --report' option to generate an html file. 
The rules section is expected to show the code for each rule. This can be linked to the result file as well.
However, when I click on any rule in my report, it fails to show the source code. 
But the actual example report [Snakemake report](https://koesterlab.github.io/resources/report.html) shows the code for  individual rules.

How do I link the code to the rule here?

Similar question - [Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57790165/include-parameters-and-source-code-in-snakemake-html-report)

Comment: The link doesn't work :(

Comment: Please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The code is displayed in the report since [version 5.5.4](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/history.html#id15). Update your SnakeMake and then it should work.

Comment: Hi, I updated the Snakemake version to 5.7.1 and I still can't display the code. It just displays the word 'source' in the code block.

Comment: Try making a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise it is impossible for us to help you farther :(

Comment: I figured it out. Snakemake report can't recognize sub-workflow snakefiles and hence fails to display code. I realized it when I was trying to make an example.