# Can external scripts be included in Snakemake report?

Tags: python, snakemake

Similar to the following questions, I could not find a definite answer to whether or not external scripts (e.g. `.py` source) can be included in report as code blocks under the rule table.

Do reports only display code that's inline within the `Snakefile`? Is there a way to include external scripts?

It's a great framework as far as I've been able to explore it!

[Include Parameters and source code in Snakemake HTML Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57790165/include-parameters-and-source-code-in-snakemake-html-report)

[Snakemake report - Code not displayed in the report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58701334/snakemake-report-code-not-displayed-in-the-report)

Comment: Looking at this report, it's definitely possible... https://koesterlab.github.io/resources/report.html (e.g. see the code for rule `plot_precision_recall`).

Comment: This was my inspiration but so far I can only see code blocks for shell and inline code. If scripts within the working directory should be picked up, then I'll try to replicate what I'm seeing in a reproducible example.

Comment: I tried various things to produce a similar template, but failed. So I can see it's possible, but don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug that appeared sometime after version `6.4.1`, I provide a minimal reproducible example in the [relevant GH issue](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1109).

One option right now is to install the old version before generating the report:

```sh
pip install snakemake==6.4.1
snakemake --report
# can revert back to the latest version
# pip install -U snakemake
```

The generated report will include code blocks for the included scripts. This is not ideal, but should work until the bug is fixed.